# Visual Studio displaying UTF-8 (without BOM) as ISO 8859-1 (characters all messed up)

Tags: visual-studio, encoding, utf-8, visual-studio-2015, character-encoding

I have no clue what happened, and i uninstalled pretty much everything on my PC and reinstalled VS 2015, but UTF-8 files (without BOM) display all messed up in VS now, as before they would work just fine.

If i save the file WITH BOM, all is well ..but that's not the goal.
If i open the file in another editor, it displays that the file is very well a UTF-8 file, and the content displays fine ..only VS is messed up.

Even fixing the characters and then doing the usual save-as, and choosing utf-8 without bom, only works as long as i don't close/reopen VS ..once i do, it's all messed up again.

It seems like everytime VS opens a file thats in UTF-8 (without BOM), VS opens it as if it where in 8859-1

Any ideas anyone ? Thanks !

**Visual Studio:**

[image: Visual Studio]

**Notepad++**

[image: Notepad++]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of pains, reinstalls, etc, i finally figuerd it out.

I really don't remember having to have to check this in the past, but apparently you have to tell VS to autodetect utf-8 files without signature:

[image]
Not sure if this was checked in the past, is some install unchecked it, or whatever ..in any case this fixes the issue.